# How can I focus the activity bar using hotkeys in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

[vscode screenshot. the section that i'm talking about is in here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3JPE.jpg)

Comment: hover over each button to see its shortcut key

Comment: i use zen mode and i just want a shortcut for focus on activity bar cuz' its not visible in zen mode at all. but i found the way and i will use your advise too. thank you.

Comment: Don't put a solution in the question. You were right to [post your own answer](/help/self-answer) :)

Answer (score 1):

i found the way.this section's title is activity bar and there is a hotkey for that motion on vscode. you can type "focus activity bar" and customize this hotkey for yourself cuz' there is no default hotkey for this motion. you have to define it. also there is hotkeys for some of the bars, you can hover them to see hotkeys for define for them directly.

Comment: This works for me but what I cannot find is how to set up a when clause for when the activity bar is then focused. You can check for focus on every single possible panel in the sidebar but not for the activity bar as far as I can see.